# Why do I keep getting Error 404 each time i try to visit a specific page on my angularproject website by adding the page directory to the url

Tags: angular, directory

This is a angular project and I have hosted it successfully but It returns error 404 each time I enter the domainname/a directory e.g

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask]

Comment: what is your web server and how you config it?

Comment: Did you mean hosting. I hosted on digital ocean

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a new directory `services` in your angular project and expect to enter this folder over your web browser? Your angular folder structure is **not** your page structure on the web page.

You need routing to point a route to a specific component. First, make sure that `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is present in your **app.component.html** and add your desired component with the route to **app-routing.module.ts**. Read more about routing [here](https://angular.io/guide/router).

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'example-route',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: ExampleComponent,
  },
];
```

*app-routing.module.ts*

Then, you can access `http://localhost:4200/example-route` and will see the content from `ExampleComponent`.

Comment: I have check with the above but still returning the error.